# How i can export an apk file with android studio including sqlite data base

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, apk

I alredy checked all th questions and nothing seems help , my problem is the database works fine with the emulator using the absolute path of the database :

String path = "/data/data/com.example.??/databases/database.db";

but when i export it as apk file the the device can't open or find the database with that path !

is that mean when i export it the real path will change ? or just i need to copy my database to specified folder in the device ,, ? can any one help me with this ,, thanks !

Comment: Do you mean when you launch to a real device? Because if that's the case, the database is not part of the APK. You would have to create a new one in the launched device.

Comment: i have created my database using sqlite db browser ,, it contains images ,, and i import it to my project using the android device monitor , if the database is not part of the APK file how can i attach the database  with it ?

Comment: So you created a Database outside of Android Studio and imported into your project & you're trying to access it and it works when you do it in the emulator but not with a real device?

Comment: yes thats the case

Comment: As far as I know, you can't copy into a real device unless you root the device.

Comment: ahh okay :/ ,, thnx mate  , appreciate ur answers :)

Comment: If you can export the working DB with DB Browser, could you use the export file in an init script?

Comment: i have no idea about that , but i did solve my problem , the solution is  - you should 1st have the database file in the assets folder in the project , and then the app should copie the database from the assests folder to the application, also i found this article "  http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/  "   it was so useful for me .

Comment: I like your solution, suggest you answer the question and mark as solved!